# Когда использовать redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

Добрый день. Я пишу SPA приложение на react + redux, в принципе подход flux понятен, но некоторые вещи вызывают вопросы. Например я вынес в глобальный store данные о авторизованном пользователе, потому что они используются во многих модулях для разделения доступа и т.д. здесь вопросов нет.

Но как быть с данными самих страниц, например у меня есть страница со статистикой, разумно ли выносить эти данные в глобальный стор (создавать экшены, редьюсеры), ведь после перехода в другой раздел они не потребуются, а в памяти они висеть будут.
Почему бы не хранить все данные о странице в локальном state?

Собственно вопрос в том, когда и какие данные действительно нужно выносить в глобальный store?

Comment: Лучше всего использовать `store` когда данные понадобятся в нескольких компонентах. Скажем, юзера там хранить - действительно хорошая идея. Если данные присутствуют только в одном компоненте - храни их в локальном стэйте. Другой полезной фичей стора - подтягивать большой массив данных до того, как они понадобятся. Скажем, данные есть только в одном компоненте, но их нужно регулярно обновлять, и вообще медленно тянутся с сервера - будет разумно их стягивать сразу после авторизации юзера(залогинился, попал в дашборд\индекс-пэйдж, тянем данные).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В глобальный стор стоит выносить те данные которые требуются в других компонентах, иначе конечно смысла нет. Например состояние компонентов-форм (инпутов) выносить куда либо за пределы компонента смысла нет.

Answer (score 0):

Какая разница где будет находиться state локально или глобально (в redux), он все равно будет находится в памяти. Redux лишь упрощает всю откладку. Данные страницы можно очистить при переходе в другую старницу, тогда в памяти висеть они не будут. Нет смысла использовать локальный state при работе с redux.